# Not Able to view image in the server

Tags: php, android

I am a beginner in android and i want to upload an image to my server but the problem is the image gets uploaded but i cannot view it properly and there is some problem but i don't know where...so please help me.

This is my android code for background activity to upload image to server

```
public class BackgroundSendActivity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    Bitmap ori_image;
    String ID, send_url, image;

    BackgroundSendActivity(Bitmap ori_image, String ID) {

        this.ori_image = ori_image;
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        send_url = "http://androidmedinfo.net23.net/sendtoserver.php";
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ori_image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        image = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);

        try {
            URL url = new URL(send_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("ID", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(ID, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("image", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(image, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return "Image Uploaded Successfully....";

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return "Error while uploading image.....";
    }
```

This is my php code for uploading the image

```
     <?php

          $id = urldecode($_POST["ID"]);
          $image = urldecode($_POST["image"]);

          $decodeImage = base64_decode("$image");
          file_put_contents("pictures/".$id.".jpg",$decodeImage);

     ?>
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Try [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to load image from server

Comment: cannot view the image in the server....it looks like a small white box